# How can I reformat JSON with awk?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have information as given below in a text file.

```
{"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:03":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:02":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:01":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:06":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:05":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:04":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}]}
```

I want that information to be like this.

```
{
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:03":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:02":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:01":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:06":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:05":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}],
"00:00:00:00:00:00:02:04":[{"controllerId":"onos-primary"}]
}
```

How can I acheieve this using Linux commandline.? I am willing to use awk or sed or simple bash

Comment: _Oh!,_ you want to format `json`.

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to be a new user.  Haven't you read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a good question yet?

Comment: yes.I do.It is the output from REST interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
awk '{sub('/^{/', "{\n", $0); sub('/}$/', "\n}", $0); gsub('/,/', ",\n", $0); print;}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

My i suggest python?

```
python -m json.tool < file.json
```

And with syntax-highlighting:

```
python -m json.tool < file.json | highlight --syntax js -O xterm256
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\{(.*)\}/{\n\1\n}/;s/,/&\n/g' file
```